# Can the Django development server be started programmatically?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to start the django development server from another module in my package. My module can import manage.py, and I want to execute the equivalent of `manage.py runserver` without using subprocess or anything of that sort (why? see below).

Currently the best solution I could come up with is to use subprocess:

```
def run_with_default_settings():
    import inspect
    import subprocess
    currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver'], cwd=currentdir)
```

However this solution seems to me rather overcomplicated, and more importantly **it is not platform independent** (for example if someone has both python 2 and python 3 and `python` is defined as python 3; or if `python` is not defined in the environment PATH... etc.).

I couldn't find any solutions online, and every way I tried to run `execute_from_command_line()` failed miserably.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just do what's in the `manage.py`:

```
import os
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web.settings')
execute_from_command_line(list_of_args)
```

This should work fine. Just remember that `execute_from_command_line` accepts originally `sys.argv` as argument, so the command `runserver` is on the index **1**:

```
list_of_args = ['', 'runserver']
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works, at least in my case, if the importing module is in the same directory in which `manage.py` resides. Otherwise, all the django imports fail:

     `File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named fitter.apps`