# How to start a Django app from another python script

Tags: python, django

I have multiple different User Interfaces for a Python app which get injected at runtime, one of which is a Django App.

NOTE - This is not a production app.  This is just for my own usage on my own PC.  I'm not worried about security at ALL.

For example, I have a CLI user interface, as well as a Django UI.  My main file is something like this:

```py
def main():
  config , test_config = load_test_config(Config, TestConfig)
  user_interface = None
  if config.user_interface() == "cli":
    from frontend.Cli import Cli
    user_interface = Cli()
  elif config.user_interface() == "django":
    from frontend.Django import Django
    user_interface = Django()

  app = TradingApplication(user_interface)
  app.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The application is quite simple for right now:

```py
# This is the main application that gets fired up.

class TradingApplication(object):

  # We inject the UI, this could be a CLI or a web app, or desktop app etc.
  def __init__(self, user_interface):
    # Save and register UI with the app
    self.user_interface = user_interface

  # Start the UI and feed the app in as well, so the UI can make calls into the app
  def start(self):
    self.user_interface.run(self)
```

All it does is invoke the User interface and pass a reference to itself in, so the UI can contact the application.

The Django.py file is in a subdirectory called 'frontend', along with the other possible front-ends I am building.  The Django class attempts to start like this:

```py
import os
import sys

class Django(object):

  def __init__(self):
    pass


  def run(self, app):
    self.app = app
    os.chdir("./frontend")
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'frontend.frontend.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'runserver'])
```

But I get this error:

> bash
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I think this has something to do with the fact that the execute_from_command_line method is expecting to be run as **main**, or something like that.

I'm not interested in alternative solutions, I'd just like to know how to trick the `execute_from_command_line` function into thinking it's being run like a normal script, and so it will start the django app for me.

Or, if there is some other mechanism for just starting a django app, I'd be interested in that.  Something like:

```py
from django.core.management import start_app
```

Then I can just call:

```py
start_app()
```

Or something magic like that would be awesome.

Comment: Did you create the `Django` class?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

@**Richard**, This is to make sense how to call django project in another python script. I am not sure does it go with your requirements or not! But if you need to know how to access in django app from other python script file. Then you may check it.

```
import os 

# change the current directory 
# to specified directory 
os.chdir(r"Drivename:\Main Folder\Subfolder\django project folder")
#Need to show the opath for  your django project folder
cwd = os.getcwd() 

# print the current directory 
 print("Current working directory is:", cwd) 
 import django
 from django.conf import settings

 print(DATABASES)
```

Its for show database but if you want to know other then can know from other configuration options in the list.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had seen something like this around and it is useful.  For this exact problem though I want an instance of the django application running, as a server, so I can actually interact with the application

Comment: realised this guy had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305289/can-the-django-development-server-be-started-programmatically

Comment: this is an outdated solution - https://gist.github.com/j4mie/708047

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I think the best way to do this is to use something like CherryPy and then mount the Django app as a WSGI application